# Angular Unit Testing: How do i call a named function

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-mocha

I have a controller, which contains a named function.

```
function controller($scope, ...){
   function foo(data){ 
     //logic for other stuff
     $log(data);
 }

 //some promise stuff
waiting.then(function(data){
  foo(data);
});
```

For the way that functions are available, i didnt want to assign foo to a scope variable, since doing something like this:

```
$scope.foo = function(data) {}
```

was frowned upon? (not sure...but since i am not calling foo from view, i dont see why i would)

My issue is, how do i call the foo function from a unit test "it" block?

i.e

```
  it('expect calling function', function(){
    foo(data);
});
```

This gives me error

Comment: where does `foo` get called from.  Maybe you ought to write a test for that method

Comment: as per my example, foo is being called by a promise chain "waiting.then()"

for SOC, I am mocking up the service that would return the promise for waiting variable., hence i have no way to "resolve" the promise

Comment: where does `waiting` come from?  maybe you can mock it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `foo` function outside controller is impossible, because `foo` is closure - inner function defined and available only within controller function body.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Lexical_scoping

I prefer controllerAs syntax for angular controller. Controller is ordinary object constructor with properties and method defined on this. 
Binding to scope arises only during evaluation ng-controller directive (or route display).

Generally then you can create controller instance in test, mock dependencies (`waiting`) and use spies for assert function call more easily.

http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/